# <Link> in React doesn't forward to a new page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-component

Consider the code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from '../../assets/crown.svg';
import './header.styles.scss';

const Header = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>

        <div className='header'>
            <Link className='logo-container' to='/'>
                <Logo className='logo' />
            </Link>
            <div className='options'>
                <Link className='option' to='/shop'>
                    SHOP
      </Link>
                <Link className='option' to='/contact'>
                    CONTACT
      </Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Header;
```

This is a header that I use in my App.

Look like this :

[image]

When I click on the **crown** the URL (in the browser) changes , but the page doesn't change , it stays on the same page.

Same thing happens with the other Links , `CONTACT` & `SHOP`.

What's wrong with the `<Link>` tag ? Why doesn't it forward to the `to` that's written on the Link tag ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup the routes? This would be in `AppRouter.js` for example:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/' component={Home} exact={true} />
            <Route path='/shop' component={Shop} exact={true }/>
            <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} exact={true} />
            <Route component={ErrorPage} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I don't have AppRouter.JS

Comment: Look at this guide https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start , then just do the same thing it is pretty straightforward of course you can put components in seperate files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want navigate your user try use NavLink
or add withRouter to component and push them to the other pages

-- NavLink solution :

```
import { NavLink, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

and then in your JSX use this instead

```
<NavLink className='logo-container' to='/'>
  <Logo className='logo' />
</NavLink>
```

-- push solution:

```
import { withRouter , BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

export your component like this

```
export default withRouter(Header);
```

then you can use any tags you want and listen at events on them

```
<p className='logo-container' onClick = {() => props.history.push('/')}>
  <Logo className='logo' />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to navigate to different components you have to define routers. So react-router-dom will know what to display.

The other thing is u cannot put BrowserRouter inside the Header component. Component `BrowserRouter` wraps the history object in the browser and passes it to down to component tree. BrowserRouter is a wrapper. Header should be placed inside the BrowserRouter but not here. just create your Header Component without BrowserRouter.

here is how you should properly implement routing in react.js

in src/omponents folder create your components for routes.

src/component/shop.js:

```
import React from "react";

const Shop = () => <div>my shop component</div>; //define your component

export default Shop;
```

create all other components like so including Header but without BrowserRouter. then in src folder create a new directory name routers. inside of it  create AppRouter.js

src/routers/AppRouter.js

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
import Shop from "../components/Shop";
//import all other routes from components directory.
import Header from "../components/Header"

const AppRouter = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={YourHomeComponent} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        <Route path="/shop" component={Shop} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
export default AppRouter;
// When react-router sees “Switch” it is going to move through your route definitions in order and it’s going to stop when it finds a match.
```

finally in app.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import AppRouter from "./routers/AppRouter";

ReactDOM.render(<AppRouter />, document.getElementById("app"));
```